# Credentials format to login into Windows Domain?

Tags: windows, login

How do I login into a Windows based server from a Mac ? domain\username or domain/username or just username ? Nothing seems to be working so far, is there any other way ? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried user@domain?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking logging onto a windows domain from a Mac takes the form of:

```
[DOMAIN]\[USERNAME]
[PASSWORD]
```

so if I were a user in the Microsoft Active Directory domain with the username of johnny.appleseed and my password was 1234qWer, that would look like

```
microsoft\johnny.appleseed
1234qWer
```

Note that the username and the password are not case sensitive I generally use all lowercase for simplicity's sake.

Note that you must have a username assigned to you in the domain with the necessary permissions on the target server for that particular login/username. Without that it will never work.

If the target (Windows) server is not domain-joined then you would use the name of the computer (sometimes called the NETBIOS name) on the network in place of the domain. But you must have a username, password and the appropriate permissions created on that server for the login to work.

I also find that when connecting to a PC via the GO > Connect to server dialog it sometimes helps to use the IP address of the target server, if you are not connecting using the server's name. Examples below.

```
smb://192.168.1.1/share
smb://bigserver/share
```